# Set user roles in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

> Hi,
>
> I have one page in that page I have to shown some details about
>   users data. If I had login by using admin role then all details are
>   visible and I login using users role some details are going to be non
>   visible

For your reference I had add the image:-

[image]

> Controller:-

```
 public ActionResult EditableUserDetails()
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = "Welcome" + ":" + " " + Session["UserName"].ToString();
            ViewBag.UserTypeId = Session["UserTypeId"].ToString();
            //List<EditableUserDetails> EditableUserDetailsobject = new List<EditableUserDetails>();
            var linq = (from db in EntityObj.Users
                        where db.IsActive == true
                        select new EditableUserDetails
                        {
                            UserId = db.UserId,
                            UserName = db.UserName,
                            Password = db.Password,
                            Category = db.Category
                        }).ToList();
            var data = linq.ToList();
            return View(data);
        }
```

> Model Class:-

```
public class EditableUserDetails
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

If I click the "Person" box it will show the all users details but I have to set this permission only for Admin role not for users role..

Is there any way to implement depends on login details.
Thank you.

**View Page:-**

```
@model IEnumerable<stg_test2.Models.EditableUserDetails>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")     
}
<input type="submit" value="Person" id="sbtPersonDetails" />
<input type="submit" value="Volunteer" id="sbtVolunteerDetails" />
<input type="submit" value="Potential Volunteer" id="sbtPotentialVolunteerDetails" />
<input type="submit" value="Child Sponcers" id="sbtChildSponcerDetails" />
<input type="submit" value="Children Details" id="sbtChildren" />
<input type="submit" value="Year Review Report" id="sbtYearReviewReport" />

<table id="tblUsers">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #7ac0da;">

            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th class="td-img">Process</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var @item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.UserName</td>
                <td>@item.Password</td>
                <td>@item.Category </td>
                <td class="td-img">
                    <img src="../Images/Edit.png" class="imgEdit" /><img src="../Images/Trash.png" class="imgDelete" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.UserId" class="hdnUserId"/></td>
            </tr>            
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show some code so that we can help.

Comment: I had add some details above mayabelle..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the code for your view, but I will go off of what you have shown.

First, I would recommend separating your domain model from your view model.  This creates separation of concerns, allows you to modify your view model without affecting your domain model (and vice versa), and allows you to only send the properties necessary for the view.

Create a view model like this:

```
public class EditableUserDetailsViewModel
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    // Include other properties from EditableUserDetails, but only those that are needed for the view to consume
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
 public ActionResult EditableUserDetails()
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = "Welcome" + ":" + " " + Session["UserName"].ToString();
        ViewBag.UserTypeId = Session["UserTypeId"].ToString();

        EditableUserDetails domainModel = (from db in EntityObj.Users
                    where db.IsActive == true
                    select new EditableUserDetails
                    {
                        UserId = db.UserId,
                        UserName = db.UserName,
                        Password = db.Password,
                        Category = db.Category
                    }).ToList();

        EditableUserDetailsViewModel viewModel = new EditableUserDetailsViewModel {
            IsAdmin = ..., // Set this boolean value based on the user's role
            // Fill in other properties needed for the view from the domain model above
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

(I would also question why you are storing a welcome message in session, but that is outside the scope of this question and answer.)

And in your view, show the admin-only parts only if `IsAdmin` is true:

```
@if (Model.IsAdmin) {
    <div>Your Person here</div>
}
```

Comment: You'd have to be more specific about what is not working. Also note that there are places in the code above that need to be filled in by you.

Comment: I had to bind list of datas in "EditableUserDetails" view from "EditableUserDetails model" but ur model returns View(viewModel);

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if this is specifically what you are looking for, but you could do this on your View:

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, role))
{
    //display the div
}
else
{
    //don't display the div
}
```

This would check to see if the user matches the roles required to view certain things and then design the View accordingly.